# How to get post values in catalog_product_save_after observer in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, post-data, event-observer

```
<?php

namespace Maxime\Helloworld\Observer;


use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface
{

 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)

 {
  $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    }

}
```

Used this code. But it didin't gives the post values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your observer constructor do:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
)
{
    $this->_request = $request;
}
```

Then in your code use `$this->_request` to fetch post params, like below :

```
$post = $this->_request->getPost();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
```